# None of my array calculation methods are working / returning values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java.  I'm trying to build a really simple departmental sales reporting system for my portfolio that declares 5 arrays (of length 12, so for a 12-month reporting period) for each department.  I have an addData method that manually adds test data into each array.  The methods that calculate and return the Q1-Q4 sales data for each department.

The problem I have is that while the arrays are storing the test data the methods don't seem to be returning any values so I'm getting 0.0 (there are no error messages). Can someone help me to fix this? The code is below:

```
public double q3Sales (double [] deptArray)
{
    //9.Q3 Sales Calculation for all departments
    deptArray = new double[monthly];
    double Q3Sum = 0;
    
    Q3Sum = deptArray[6]+deptArray[7]+deptArray[8];
    return Q3Sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Quarterly_Report n=new Quarterly_Report();
        n.addData();
        
        //11. Display Quarterly Sales Table in the Eclipse Console
        
        System.out.println("------------");
        System.out.println("QUARTERLY DEPARTMENTAL SALES REPORT");
        System.out.println("------------");
        System.out.println(n.q1Sales(n.electrical));
        
        System.out.println("        \t Electrical \t Kitchen \t Bathroom \t Soft Furnishings \t Accessories");
    
        
        System.out.print("Q3 Sales");
        System.out.print("\t"+ "\t");
        System.out.print(n.q3Sales(n.electrical));
        System.out.print("\t" + "\t");
        System.out.print(n.q3Sales(n.kitchen));
        ... etc
```

1. I am expecting the correct, calculated Q3Sum figure to be displayed.  But it just shows 0.0.  No errors displayed so I don't know how to go about and fix this as it seems the calculation just isn't being performed.
2. I have tried using 2D arrays but they are more complex than my ability at the moment.
3. I've tried using a for loop in q3Sales() but I get the same problem.

Comment: What is `n` supposed to be?

Comment: Why do you create a new `deptArray`? Using a debugger or even just logging might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In your `q3Sales`-method you are reassigning the paramter array.
When instatiated, arrays are always filled with `0` (`0.0` as `double` or `false` as `boolean`).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise Arrays were initialised by default.  Yours and Murenik's answers worked

Comment: @NK if it helped make sure to accept an answer

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the `deptArray` in the method, which is wrong. Instead you should use the array passed to the method:

```java
public double q3Sales (double [] deptArray)
{
    //9.Q3 Sales Calculation for all departments
    return deptArray[6]+deptArray[7]+deptArray[8];
}
```

Comment: Better answer than mine :) But maybe you want to add the fact that arrays are filled with 0 by default. It might make things clearer.